# Firebase Swift Async Object creation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider I have entities in my db named categories and and categoryItems structured like so

```
categories

  - categoryID

    - name

categoryItems

  - itemId
   - categoryId
   - name
   - price
```

Obviously more fields are stored but this is for an example. What is the best way to create a new categories object that includes all of the category items as their own separate object? Looking for more of general concept than anything...

For example in Swift I would have objects like so

```
class Category {
  var name: String
  var items: [CategoryItem]
}

class CategoryItem {
  var name: String
  var price: Float
}
```

Below is an example of how I am currently doing this however it seems like a bad structure if say there were 3 or 4 properties that needed calls to the database.

```
ref.child("categories/").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let categories = snapshot.children
  while let category = categories.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
      ref.child("categoryItems/").queryOrderedByValue("categoryID").queryEqualToValue((category.key)).observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
      let categoryItems = snapshot.children

      let category = Category()
      while let item = categoryItems.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
          let i = categoryItem(name: item.name, price: item.price)
          category["items"].append(i)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: You should look through Firebase documentation, it is well written and you'll learn more than one answer here could provide.

Comment: Hi Daniel! I am aware of how to make it happen I am just more curious how others get the task done as the current way I am doing things seems like I am doing a lot of async to generate a single object.

Comment: You didn't post any code with async function calls in it. Post what you have tried, and maybe someone has done something similar and can help. I'm not really sure what you're asking in this question

Comment: First thing is there is no concept of Objects in Firebase. The only components you have to work with are parent and child nodes which are part of a JSON structure. Second thing is that a new categories *node* would be created when you write data to Firebase that doesn't already exist  - it's not an object where you create it and then populate it's variables. The question is super vague but I think you may be asking what would be the structure of a categories node that would have a reference to multiple items? Perhaps if you update the question we can better assist.

Comment: Hi Jay! I was referring to actually creating objects using the JSON data in my Swift application. Or do people generally just store the snapshot and never create objects of their data when using firebase in Swift? I have added an example of how I would currently do something like this